# Does anyone know if NSUserDefaults get uninstalled when deleting a sandboxed app in OSX?

Tags: macos

I'm curious about how a sandboxed app, handle uninstalling. and how NSUserDefaults get affected by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how you delete it.  If you just remove `/Applications/TheApp.app` then no, as the sandboxed app's files (including `NSUserDefaults` related files) are in `~/Library/Containers/com.domain.theapp`.

However if you use tools like *AppZapper* or *AppCleaner* etc., then they will doubtless remove the container as well.  However that is up to them.

Comment: I was reading about it, also realize that when the app is on the sandbox, the NSUserDefaults are part of the sandbox library >> preferences folder, from a OSX development point of view there is no way to test is deleting the app delete the sandbox (the app file is never part of the application folder), but while distributing from the Mac App Store, deleting the app while holding a click in the icon in the mission control, does show an x the same way that you will delete an app on iphone or ipad, that makes me wonder if that's the only case when the sandbox folder get deleted.

Comment: @AndresCano I don't know.  I would imagine the only way to find out is to test it.

Comment: You're right!, I just checked you answer on the top, still a valid answer. thanks!

Comment: ApZapper does not clear UserDefault in my case. Maybe because its a sandboxed app?